# Canvas not creating text

Tags: javascript, text, html5-canvas

So basicly I got this little bit of code that checks the end of the game, it should display victory when you killed all the enemies and GameOver when you didn't. Thing is, with this bit of code, the "victory" happens, but when defeated he doesn't show anything (the debugger shows the string is correct tho)

```
playing=false;
gameOver=true;

var resultText="You Lost!";

if(enemies.length==0){
    Debugger.log("VICTORY!");
    resultText="VICTORY!";
}

context.font = "70px Comic Sans MS";
context.fillStyle = grd;
context.textAlign = "center";
Debugger.log("ResultText: "+ resultText);
context.fillText(resultText, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
```

Comment: My grd works perfectly fine, as I said he even showed the "victory" part in filltext, it's only the "you lost" that he doesn't write.

    // Create gradient
        grd = context.createLinearGradient(0,384,1024,384);
        grd.addColorStop(0,"#00CED1");
        grd.addColorStop(0.5, "yellow")
        grd.addColorStop(1,"red");

Answer (score 1):

The code you've provided appears correct. Do the declarations for the variables look something like this. This was what I added to get it to work.

```
var cxt = document.getElementById('canvasMain');
var context = cxt.getContext('2d')
var grd = "blue";
var enemies = ["schoolBully", "busDriver"];
```

And have you tested to make sure length actually hits 0?

Comment: yup that's exact for filling the gaps, so basicly if there are no more enemies (debugger also showed me there were 0 enemies en it showed victory in text so there everything works. But with defeat it showed there were still enemies in the array, he also returned "ResultText You Lost!" but it just doesn''t do the last line for some odd reason.